# same line behaves correctly or gives me an error message depending on file position

Tags: python, web.py

gives me an error message:

```
class logger:
    session = web.ctx.session #this line
```

doesn't give me an error message:

```
class create:
    def GET(self):
        # loggedout()
        session = web.ctx.session #this line
        form = self.createform()
        return render.create(form)
```

Why?

Comment: What is the error message that it gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class logger:
    print('Hi')
```

prints `Hi`. Statements under a class definition gets run at definition time.

A function definition like this one:

```
def GET(self):
    # loggedout()
    session = web.ctx.session #this line
    form = self.createform()
    return render.create(form)
```

is also a statement. It creates the function object which is named `GET`. But the code inside the function does not get run until the `GET` method is called.

This is why you get an error message in the first case, but not the second.

Answer (score 1):

`web.ctx` can't be used in that scope. It's a thread-local object that `web.py` initializes before it calls `GET/POST/etc.` and gets discarded afterwards.